# Grouped bar chart: "bottom" group name position

Tags: vega-lite

I have a Vega Lite grouped bar chart: [Vega Editor link](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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-Ms0R2AxaDRHmH5hDhsI5B+KGEcewoXkJ9a3vBuappEUm4ZE3Iuj+O7UlkNJDrxdRgSBmmwbOaRhE+9h-AZ7jUjEtisVCRbgj877cUelQAILCiF9kzo2eYhKC4wGWMTjfMqbE7uCSLUlZx4ADK3JFlE6SxLhWAZCLzvJqVpK4Gq8t5WWVOFJ75dpHwRFYSIxAZuRMf6OqVc8TiuLFgE8cefEkc1IlpExXy2DkXXapySU4UN3SefVFzZSefEANKTY5aDqimtHfn4aH+slfK+WkLlhAiG3oHxABq4WTQAukoshIAgcAXEUSAAO6+Ko6ggP0ICYHQgi-eglypJwcwAATCCYDDtHQ5iI2oiO2JQYgAKSIxAwg4DgSBkL9SiYP9sgQAAZmwRQIEYoBQDohSCGoMMgIYIMMAglDXQoiN8wLr6CG9jRIAY6AzBYOBwL4sqJmzggc1zFyGAA5NsWvC1rbpa5LSjSxccvmArYNvHTnPYGURgFvLiuygCTsgG9Kvswwtvc6LgtJE7SsWIjABUiNWHA-DhFLMuOxbztJAgzOe2r3sa+gDNM2oAAUfvmwrQd+En+sKJQThFFrACUiMANSI1riMALKN4jIpazHFyYGwbCCJDOBgx9IAA+09BoKAECYHA-fUeDyBFAA1hcTBIEUjRnGwyg0LIZBj8cPf8-ImggHTNCBISh6Vo0kOYNDFw3KNlhU-HFyM5vX3BEoMhFJgu9sNPIAQH5o0E+Z8LiAIQIXXwgcXYgFfnAVe6BlD6CgGUN+O9wYQDJlALeO90i2HBmkUA5MyClAoJPMBQClAgMEOffOCci7MyplDbmABFBgSBZDX0xtnZurdqyVylgADxoDLUAJC4x0x0AEDBqsYagDdugQQbB0Hg0EbvahtCA7PxNsImWshvaCHBlAHujN1GnxoWbLRlsmE325sKGgpQoCQzkI0aAOg5FNA4RTB2ABidcyhwhIFsI0HxcA6acnCHTd2vRwZdx7n3MxoD0BxN7jQfuT9LboFflvHQYMjFyBPrgrQp8Aa7wnkUNg89ubUw4ZgleZQf7gyQLo3eyg2DIC3iOEeMBrAxN6EAA) which looks as follows:

[image: current grouped bar chart]

I would like to move the "Currency" group names (`UST`, `BTC`, `ETH` etc.) to the bottom of the chart, so that the currency label appears *below* the respective bars (as if it were a normal X-axis).

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by adding `"header": {"orient": "bottom"}` to the `column` encoding ([editor link](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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-Ms0R2AxaDRHmH5hDhsI5B+KGEcewoXkJ9a3vBuappEUm4ZE3Iuj+O7UlkNJDrxdRgSBmmwbOaRhE+9h-AZ7jUjEtisVCRbgj877cUelQAILCiF9kzo2eYhKC4wGWMTjfMqbE7uCSLUlZx4ADK3JFlE6SxLhWAZCLzvJqVpK4Gq8t5WWVOFJ75dpHwRFYSIxAZuRMf6OqVc8TiuLFgE8cefEkc1IlpExXy2DkXXapySU4UN3SefVFzZSefEANKTY5aDqimtHfn4aH+slfK+WkLlhAiG3oHxABq4WTQAukoshIAgcAXEUSAAO6+Ko6ggP0ICYHQgi-eglypJwcwAATCCYDDtHQ5iI2oiO2JQYgAKSIxAwg4DgSBkL9SiYP9sgQAAZmwRQIEYoBQDohSCGoMMgIYIMMAglDXQoiN8wLr6CG9jRIAY6AzBYOBwL4sqJmzggc1zFyGAA5NsWvC1rbpa5LSjSxccvmArYNvHTnPYGURgFvLiuygCTsgG9Kvswwtvc6LgtJE7SsWIjABUiNWHA-DhFLMuOxbztJAgzOe2r3sa+gDNM2oAAUfvmwrQd+En+sKJQThFFrACUiMANSI1riMALKN4jIpazHFyYGwbCCJDOBgx9IAA+09BoKAECYHA-fUeDyBFAA1hcTBIEUjRnGwyg0LIZBj8cPf8-ImggHTNCBISh6Vo0kOYNDFw3KNlhU-HFyM5vX3BEoMhFJgu9sNPIAQH5o0E+Z8LiAIQIXXwgcXYgFfnAVe6BlD6CgGUN+O9wYQDJlALeO90gHngEgJBCDQCM1PrIH+6AmBsGwGwZO4M0igHJmQUoFBJ5gKAUoEBghz75wTkXZmVMobcwAIoMCQOQjGiNs7N1btWSuUsAAeNAZagGYXGOmOgAgYNVjDUAbt0CCDYOg8GCjd5cJ4QHZ+JslEy1kN7QQ4MoA90ZmY0+3CzaWMtoIm+3NhQ0FKFASGchGjQB0Lopo4iKYOwAMTrmUOEJAthGjRLgHTTk4Q6bu16ODLuPc+6uNAegXJvcaD9yfpbdAr8t46DBo4uQJ9cFaFPgDXeE8ihsHntzam4jMErzKD-cGSAbG72ULQpAW8RwjxgNYbJvQgA)):

[image]